# Connecting to IBM zOS system/DB2 table with a PHP Cloud Foundry app

Tags: php, db2, cloud-foundry, db2-zos

Is it possible to connect from w3ibm.bluemix/PHP Cloud Foundry app to a bluezone zOS system and it's DB2 table?

I already connecting to a DB2 table on w3ibm.bluemix (using a db2 service and having a table there). It worked, but now I would like to connect to a zOS system.

When I try to connect locally I receive this error message:

> An attempt to connect to the database server failed because of a licensing problem. SQLSTATE=42968 SQLCODE=-1598

I have a lincense file but its in jar format (db2jcc_license_cisuz.jar) and I have no idea how to add a jar to a php project..

When I try to connect from w3ibm.bluemix (Cloud) - I receive this error - using the same code:

> The remote host "******.UK.IBM.COM" was not found. SQLSTATE=08001 SQLCODE=-1336

Thx in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For connecting from IBM Bluemix to a blue zone zOS DB2 with a PHP Cloud Foundry app,

1. Deticated [Secure Gateway](https://w3-connections.ibm.com/wikis/home?lang=en-us#!/wiki/Secure%20Gateway%20Client%20as%20a%20Service/page/Secure%20Gateway%20Client%20as%20a%20Service%20%28SGCaaS%29),
2. [PHP buildpack](https://github.com/ibmdb/php-buildpack) with DB2 extension and
3. zOS [DB2 license file copied to the right place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722710/where-to-place-z-os-license-file-when-push-cloud-foundry-php-app-to-bluemix)

are needed.

For point 2, PHP buildpack, you just have to update your **manifest.yml**, adding or updating build-pack value to:

```
buildpack: https://github.com/ibmdb/php-buildpack
```

Then you have to set the version of PHP used to one that has DB2 extension pre-setted, so it's installed during build. For that you need a **composer.json** file in your project root folder - example with this value:

```
{
    "require": {
        "php": "7.0.16"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to find a Db2-connect gateway server (or secure gateway) that is located in a zone reachable from bluemmix with the relevant ports opened.  There may be approvals required for such access, specific credentials, encryption/key-exchange requirements etc.

I suggest you engage the people who look after the target Db2-system, or the service owner(s) for the application(s) that manage the target data.