# Where to place Z/OS license file when push Cloud Foundry PHP app to Bluemix?

Tags: php, cloud-foundry, db2-zos, hybrid-cloud

I would like to connect from Bluemix to Z/OS system, using SecureGatway, but I don't have a Z/OS license file (most probably: db2consv_zs.lic file). I receive SQLSTATE=42968. The SG tunel looks okay.

If I get the license.. where do I have to copy/install it when I push my local project to CIO Bluemix? Shall I copy it to the [php buildpack](https://github.com/ibmdb/php-buildpack.git)? And will it be registered in the cloud environment? Is there any other way to connect from a Blue Foundry PHP app to a blue zone Z/OS system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**1, License DB2 driver on Bluemix for zOS**

The license file must be placed into a folder of the PHP instance on the server. The DB2 extension is installed during deployment of the Cloud Foundry app. I found no way to copy the license file during build or deployment. But I found a way to copy the lic file after deployment: I added the lic file to my project and then I copied it over with a php file that I run from browser. This is the line:

```
$src = '/home/vcap/app/lib/db2consv_zs.lic';    
$dst = '/home/vcap/app/ibmdb_clidriver/license/db2consv_zs.lic';
if (!copy($src, $dst)) {
echo "failed to copy $src...\n";
```

Secure Gateway also must be set properly to connect from Bluemix to a blue zone zOS DB2. [Instructions](https://w3-connections.ibm.com/wikis/home?lang=en-us#!/wiki/Secure%20Gateway%20Client%20as%20a%20Service/page/Secure%20Gateway%20Client%20as%20a%20Service%20%28SGCaaS%29).

**2, License DB2 driver on Local machine in IBM blue zone for zOS**

The license problem disappeared when I **installed** **license** for DB2 Connect.

"To connect to an IBM mainframe database server you require a licensed DB2 Connect product. You cannot connect directly to an IBM mainframe Data Server using a IBM data server client." [link](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.dbconn.doc/doc/c0008447.html)

"You can add [DB2 Connect™](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.swg.im.dbclient.install.doc/doc/c0022612.html) capability to any client or driver."

[DB2 license files](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/r0006748.html)

Use [db2licm](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.cmd.doc/doc/r0002451.html) command to register the license.

How to install DB2 Connect to Bluemix is still open, alternatively Secure Gateway might contain DB2 Connect.. but not sure .. and a connection server can be used also. Will add comments later.