# Can I install DB2 Connect to Bluemix to conect to Mainframe Z/OS?

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, zos, secure-gateway, db2-connect

Is DB2 Connect installation and license installation during build/deploy a good way to ensure mainframe connectivity to IBM Blue zone? My PHP Cloud Foundry app is on w3ibm.bluemix.

If yes shall I update the forked [PHP Buildpack](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/php-buildpack) on GIT, by adding DB2 Connect to it? 
Or shall I use some sort of docker image for this? 
Any other idea?

Comment: I use also Secure Gateway, but have some problem there too with licensing if connecting from workstation or in general if connecting from Bluemix.

Comment: In general, you should avoid forking a buildpack if at all possible.  It creates a maintenance burden for you and if you don't merge in upstream changed & build new versions frequently can delay your apps from receiving timely updates to dependencies provided by the buildpack.

Comment: I will keep in mind @DanielMikusa! I have a DB2 Connect license file, that should be placed and also installed on the cloud environment of my Bluemix app. I can't place it to my project source folder.. license file should be next to the DB2 driver files... so I think I have to add this file somehow to the environment that the buildpack builds... any idea how to do it?

Comment: Probably a separate question, but if you put it in with the app you could use a `.profile` script to move it to the location where it needs to exist.  That script will run before your app starts.  Another option might be using multi-buildpack support.  You could create a buildpack that just provides your DB2 resources.  https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/buildpacks/custom.html#contract

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that there is no need to install a DB2 Connect. I could not install it anyway on Bluemix. There might be services for this, but at the end I had to use DB2 PHP extension of the PHP build-pack and after deploy I copied the license file to the license folder from PHP code. Details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50722710/where-to-place-z-os-license-file-when-push-cloud-foundry-php-app-to-bluemix).